# OLS Regression Results

Tags: python, numpy, regression, statsmodels

I am trying to do an "OLS Regression Results" ,to a college project, and my code is this:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import numpy as np

data=np.loadtxt('file.txt',skiprows=1)
season=data[:nb,0]
tod=data[:nb,1]
obs=data[:nb,2]
pr=data[:nb,3]

data_lm = ols('pr ~ tod + season',data=data).fit()
table = sm.stats.anova_lm(data_lm, typ=2) 
data_lm.summary()
print(table)
```

It gives me this error "PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
    pr ~ tod) + season"

I think the error is in the format of my data. The text file contains 4 different columns (season, tod, obs and pr).

```
season:[3., 3., 1., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 1., 3., 3., 1., 3., 2., 3., 3., 3.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 3., 1., 2., 1., 3., 1., 1., 2., 1., 3., 3., 1., 1.,
       1., 2., 3.]

tod:[2., 4., 1., 2., 2., 2., 4., 1., 3., 3., 1., 3., 3., 2., 2., 4., 3.,
       3., 4., 3., 3., 2., 4., 1., 3., 4., 1., 1., 1., 3., 3., 4., 3., 3.,
       4., 4., 4.]

obs:[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  5.,  5.,
        5.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  9.,  9., 12., 12., 12., 12., 12., 13., 13.,
       16., 16., 17., 19., 19., 19., 20., 20., 20., 20., 24.]

pr:[0. , 0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
       0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 1. , 1. , 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4,
       1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.9, 2. , 2. , 2. ]
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is a basic NumPy `ndarray` object. These accept integers, slices, or other "array like" objects when you index them with `[]`. However, the `ols` function explicitly says in [the documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.ols.html?highlight=ols#statsmodels.formula.api.ols):

> data must define `__getitem__` with the keys in the formula

That means `data` must be a pandas `DataFrame`, a dictionary, or a NumPy [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html), with a `__getitem__` method that accepts `str` objects as indices.

Comment: It can also be a dictionary. `{"pr": pr, "tod": tod, "season": season}`

Comment: @Josef Yes, it can be a dict, which is listed in the last sentence :)